# Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext

Tags: maven, spring-boot, embedded-jetty

I am trying to use jetty-maven-plugin and see an issue : [WARNING] Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@21ba83e3
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.juli.logging.Log: Provider org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog not a subtype

I saw few posts with similar error and saw that tomcat-juli is the jar that has the issue. But I don't see it in my project dependencies. I am not using AWT as well.

````
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.ceg.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>mint-platform-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.ceg.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>notification-adapters</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.oinp.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>oinp-metrics-app</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.platform.integration.messaging.crypto</groupId>
            <artifactId>messaging-crypto-client</artifactId>
            <version>release-1.13</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>idps-sdk</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.intuit.idps</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
         <!--Rest- Assured dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.Final</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>

         <!--Hikari connection pool changes -->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
           <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>${hikari.cp.version}</version>
         </dependency>
        <!--  <dependency>
             <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
             <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
             <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
         </dependency> -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jersey -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>

     <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <instrumentation>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/models/**</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/springConfig/**</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/common/**</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/resources/**</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/kafka/**</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/kafka/producers/**</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/scheduler/controller/**</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/MetricsReporterApplication.class</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/SQSAsyncClientFactoryImpl.class</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/SQSClientImpl.class</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/SESWebHookEventConsumer.class</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/SendGridWebHookService.class</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </instrumentation>
                    <check>
                        <branchRate>60</branchRate>
                        <lineRate>95</lineRate>
                        <totalBranchRate>80</totalBranchRate>
                        <totalLineRate>97</totalLineRate>
                        <packageLineRate>97</packageLineRate>
                        <packageBranchRate>80</packageBranchRate>
                        <haltOnFailure>true</haltOnFailure>
                        <regexes>
                            <regex>
                                <pattern>com.intuit.ceg.platform.notifications.services.EventConsumerHelper.class</pattern>
                                <branchRate>97</branchRate>
                                <lineRate>97</lineRate>
                            </regex>
                        </regexes>
                    </check>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.git.commit.id.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>revision</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <configuration>

                    <dotGitDirectory>${project.basedir}/.git</dotGitDirectory>
                    <skipPoms>true</skipPoms>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>9.4.18.v20190429</version>
                <configuration>
                    <httpConnector>
                        <port>8080</port>
                    </httpConnector>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>240</scanIntervalSeconds>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build> ```
````

Comment: Run `$ mvn dependency:tree` and post the results.  That should include the entire list of resolved dependencies, including your transitive ones, and any that might come from parent poms (that you didn't include in your question)

Comment: Edit your question to update it please. don't link to external content like google drive.

Comment: Cant do it. Size is more than the limits.. How do I share?

Comment: Are there any specific libraries that i should looking to exclude for this issue?

Comment: Then delete your pom snippet.  Only include the dependency:tree output (it's more relevant anyway)

Comment: Option 2 is to use the Eclipse Jetty issue tracker and post a question there about it. - https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues

Answer (score 5):

Just update your jetty version. it should work. i too was facing this issue. i had below configuration

```xml
<groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>9.4.6.v20170531</version>
```

which was working fine till when my project was a simple hello world kind of.. but started getting issue when i updated my pom.xml with other stuffs. So then i update jetty configuration as below

```xml
<groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
<artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>9.4.12.v20180830</version>
```